# Macro to delete cells highlighted by conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, conditional-formatting

I was looking for a way to automatically remove duplicates in a given range with a macro but all I could find : it's either remove duplicates from a list or remove duplicates from a cell.

I thought about it and the process I started is as follows:

1-) Show all duplicates in the range with conditional formatting

2-) Delete with a macro all cells highlighted by conditional formatting

But I'm stuck at the second step. So is there a way to delete cells colored by a macro ? (Please how to proceed?)

Thanks

Comment: Why does the [built-in duplicate removal](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d) not work for you?

Comment: Also, have you done any prior research on how to find colored cells in a macro? Did you for example do a websearch? What did you find? Did you pass [this page](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-macro-to-select-cells-adjacent-to-those-with-a-specific-fill-color-conditional-formatting.1013199/)? If you did, why did it not work for you? Please [edit] your question to include all these details.

Comment: What do you mean by "Delete"? Clear content? Delete cells when shifting other cells up (left) within a range? All over the sheet? Populate source range with only unique values? Does the source range contain cells with formulas that should be kept, or are there only numbers (dates, text)? In any case, using conditional formatting is a completely unnecessary step for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your task description correctly, then this code will do the job:

```
Sub DeleteDoublesFromSelection()
Dim rSourceRange As Range, oCell As Range, aArea As Range
Dim cDictionary As Variant
Dim sCellTextRepresentation As String
    Set cDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rSourceRange = Selection
    For Each aArea In rSourceRange.Areas
        For Each oCell In aArea.Cells
            sCellTextRepresentation = oCell.Text
            If sCellTextRepresentation <> vbNullString Then
                If cDictionary.Exists(sCellTextRepresentation) Then
                    oCell.Clear
                Else
                    cDictionary.Add sCellTextRepresentation, oCell
                End If
            End If
        Next oCell
    Next aArea
End Sub
```

*Again, conditional formatting is a visualization tool, not a calculation tool. Using it to remove duplicates is a bad idea*

Comment: Well it works. But now it would be very useful if we could remove the duplicates only in the N-th column by referring to the contents of the columns no longer containing duplicates (the one we have just purified thanks to this code). How to achieve it?